# Update multiple Records CF-ORM

Tags: coldfusion

In several data structures with my application I have an attribute named "IsPrimary". One issue I am having is that with for each User they can only have 1 primary address but have multiple address. What I am trying to figure out is with in cf9's implementation of hibernate how can I update any existing record that has the attribute IsPrimary as true to false if a new record or updated record is saved with IsPrimary being true.

This is my existing save method

```
public UserAddress function save(required UserAddress)
{
    var userAcc = entityLoadByPK('UserAccount', arguments.UserAddress.getUserID());
    arguments.UserAddress.setUserID(userAcc);

    entitySave(arguments.UserAddress);

    return arguments.UserAddress;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for a DB trigger.

Comment: Duh, I wasn't even thinking. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do it at `preInsert()` if you like.